# What is this houseplant with woody stem and varigated leaves?

Tags: houseplants, watering, plant-care

What is the name of the plant pictured below and what is its watering cycle?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *[Ficus benjamina](http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/ficus-benjamina-variegata/)* 'Variagata'. It needs little water (about once every two weeks) and little light (shade or half shade, to full sun), so it is not a very difficult plant.

From my own experience, it is susceptible to scale insects.

Comment: Thanks man helped a lot, any advice for this scale insect prevention .

Comment: No, I wish I knew how to prevent scale.

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=scale

Comment: Where does this plant reside?  This plant is very sensitive to change, fyi.  Don't be moving it from place to place.  Don't worry about scale, just be looking for scale, for white fly, for spider mite for wooly aphids...grins!  If this plant is out of doors, you need to look closer and more often.  Is this plant is planted in garden soil?  Then you need to be transplanting it into sterilized potting soil.  You will be looking for insects regularly if this is garden soil. Have you fertilized?  A healthy plant can take care of itself from insects and disease.

Comment: Ugh, and watering once every two weeks is a major stretch for this ficus.  Yet, hey, your plant looks healthy and happy. "Don't fix it if it ain't broke"?  Do you have a covered porch or patio?  All indoor plants get a boost from spending the summer outside on a covered patio with absolutely no chance of getting into direct sunlight?  Still more light and the plant can make and store carbohydrates in its roots to get it through the winter.  Do NOT worry about scale.  Happens rarely, easy to control.  Same with spider mite and white fly. We will change you watering once the soil gets changed.

Comment: Thanks @stormy , This plant is residing in Sitting room, I'm living in Arabia so can't put it outside it will become crisp within a day with temperature reaching 46C And room temperature is good with enough filtered light. And at night i turn on 9v bulb so there is enough light for plants. Gardener planted in Fresh soil, i read about it that it doesn't like to be moved alot. I made a routine of placing all plants on weekends at 3PM under shade in porch . I have bamboo , Money plant, Ficus benjamina, Dieffenbachia maculata, Aloe Vera, Basil(Rehan in Arabic) .

Comment: Ficus benjamina loves stability of its environment.  You do not need to keep this plant under lights the entire day.  Plants need darkness just like we do.   So, you have a covered porch? What temps happen at night?  They could stay out on that covered porch for most of the summer.  Grins, what is 'Fresh Soil'?  Keep your plants under the cover of the porch and you won't have to acclimate them to go back into the indoor environment.

Comment: Update: I took this plant to office and was doing very well. But when i changed my job and moved to new company the person who took responsibility overwatered it during lockdown and there was no air circulation and it died